# Prove the Fourier Transform of $f(x-x_{o})$ is $F(\omega)e^{-j \omega x_{o}}$

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform

This is a recommended problem for an engineering analysis course. I believe I've forgotten something required to complete it.

$Given\:F(\omega)=\mathscr{F}\{f(x)\}=\int_{-inf}^{inf}f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx$

$Prove\:that\:\mathscr{F}\{f(x-x_{o})\}=F(\omega)e^{-j\omega x_{0}}$

I was instructed to use what is below to help solve the problem, but wasn't sure how it proved helpful.

$x^{'}=x-x_{0}\Longrightarrow x=x^{'}+x_{0}$

$\mathscr{F}[x-x_{0}]=\int_{-inf}^{inf}f(x-x_{0})e^{-j\omega x}dx$

Comment: Don't put text in MathJax unless you absolute must, and then use `\text{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{F}\left[f(x-x_0)\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x-x_0)e^{-j\omega x}dx = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
x' = x-x_0 \Leftrightarrow x = x'+x_0 \\
dx = dx' \\
x \rightarrow - \infty \Leftrightarrow x' \rightarrow - \infty \\
x \rightarrow + \infty \Leftrightarrow x' \rightarrow + \infty
\end{array}
\right] = \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x')e^{-j\omega(x'+x_0)}dx' = \\
&= e^{-j\omega x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x')e^{-j\omega x'}dx'= \left[x:= x'\right] = \\
&= e^{-j\omega x_0}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx}_{\mathscr{F}\left[f(x)\right]} = \\
&= e^{-j\omega x_0}F(\omega)
\end{aligned}
$$